# If $x \in (a, b)$ and $xy + z(1-y) \in (a,b)$, what can I say about $y$ and $z$?

Tags: inequality

Suppose that:

$$x \in (a, b)$$
and
$$xy + z(1-y) \in (a,b),$$

where $(a,b) \subseteq (0,1)$, while $y$ and $z$ are real number.

What can I say about $y$ and $z$?

Of course, when $y = 1$, then the two expression coincides.

If $y = 0$, then $z \in (a,b)$.

In general, I have that:

$$a+z(1-y)<xy<b+z(1-y)$$

If $y > 0$, then:

$$\frac{a+z(1-y)}{y}<x<\frac{b+z(1-y)}{y},$$

while if $y < 0$, then:

$$\frac{b+z(1-y)}{y}<x<\frac{a+z(1-y)}{y}.$$

This is where I'm stuck. What can I do further in order to establish some properties for $y$ and $z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the general expression shall read:
$$
a - z\left( {1 - y} \right) < xy < b - z\left( {1 - y} \right)
$$
Then, apart from the special cases $y=0,1$ as you already determined, for the rest
you can better proceed if you gather all the conditions together.
So for the case $0<y$  write
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  y < 0 \hfill \cr 
  a < x < b \hfill \cr 
  {{b - z\left( {1 - y} \right)} \over y} < x < {{a - z\left( {1 - y} \right)} \over y} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

and then
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  y < 0 \hfill \cr 
  a < x < b \hfill \cr 
  {{b - z\left( {1 - y} \right)} \over y} < a < x < b < {{a - z\left( {1 - y} \right)} \over y} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

that is:
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  y < 0 \hfill \cr 
  a < x < b \hfill \cr 
  a - z\left( {1 - y} \right) < by \hfill \cr 
  ay < b - z\left( {1 - y} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Can you carry on from here?